# Showing the unboundedness of the function $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, metric-spaces

$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6} & \text{falls } (x, y)^t \neq (0, 0)^t \\
,0 & \text{sonst}
\end{cases}$

Show that ${g|_{B_r(0)}}$ is unbounded for every${(r > 0)}$ and show discontinuous at $((x, y) = (0, 0))$, but continuous on $(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\})$

unbounded:

Proof that $(g|B_r(0)$) is unbounded for every $(r > 0)$:

Assume, for contradiction, that $(g|B_r(0))$ is bounded for some $(r > 0)$. This means there exists a positive number $(M)$ such that $(|g(x)| \leq M)$ for all $(x)$ in the open ball $(B_r(0))$.

Consider the point $(x = \left(\frac{r}{2}, 0\right)\) \in \(B_r(0))$. Since $(g)$ is defined as $(g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R})$, we have $(g(x) = g\left(\frac{r}{2}, 0\right))$

However, we can choose a sequence of points $(x_n = \left(\frac{r}{2}, \frac{1}{n}\right))$ in $(B_r(0))$ for which $(|g(x_n)|)$ becomes arbitrarily large as $(n)$ tends to infinity.

Thus, we have a contradiction, which implies that $(g|B_r(0))$ is unbounded for every $(r > 0)$.

showing the discontinuousness:

\textbf{Proof:}

To prove that the function is discontinuous at $((0, 0))$ but continuous on $(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\})$, we need to show that the function exhibits a discontinuity at the point $((0, 0)) and that it is continuous everywhere else.

\textbf
{1. Discontinuity at $((0, 0))$:}

To demonstrate the discontinuity at $((0, 0))$, we will find two different paths approaching $((0, 0))$ such that the function has different limits along these paths.

Consider the paths $(y = mx)$ and $(y = x^2)$, where $(m)$ is any real number. As $(x)$ approaches $(0)$, along the line $(y = mx)$, the function $(f(x, mx))$ approaches a certain limit. However, along the curve $(y = x^2)$, the function $(f(x, x^2))$ approaches a different limit. Thus, the function is discontinuous at $((0, 0))$.

\textbf
{2. Continuity on $(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}):}$

To prove the continuity of the function everywhere else, we need to show that the limit of the function as $((x, y))$ approaches any point $((a, b))$ in $(\mathbb{R}^2) (excluding \((0, 0)))$ exists and is equal to the function value at $((a, b))$.

Consider any point $((a, b))$ in $(\mathbb{R}^2)$ excluding $((0, 0))$. We can define a neighborhood $(B_\epsilon((a, b)))$ around $((a, b))$, where $(\epsilon > 0)$ and
$(\epsilon)$ is sufficiently small. For all points $((x, y))$ within this neighborhood, we can show that the limit of the function $(f(x, y))$ as $((x, y))$ approaches $((a, b))$ exists and is equal to $(f(a, b))$. This establishes the continuity of the function on
$(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\})$

Therefore, we have proven that the function is discontinuous at $((0, 0))$ but continuous on $(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\})$.

Are my proofs correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the path $x = y^3$, and compute the limit along that path you get
$$
\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{y^5}{2y^6} = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{1}{2y} = \infty
$$

This shows both unboundness and discontinuity.